# Inserting a record to Msaccess database

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Can anybody help me on inserting a record in to msaccess database using visualbasic.The record entries are made in the form.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've not got 2008 but here's one way to do it using 2005:

```
    ' Open connection to db
    Dim connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\TestDB.mdb;")

    connection.Open()

    ' Create a command to execute
    Dim command = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES (100, 'MyName');", connection)

    ' Execute SQL
    command.ExecuteReader()

    ' Close the connection
    connection.Close()
```

You'll have to get the values from the form and put them into the INSERT SQL statement.

It all depends on how you want to connect to the database. ODBC, ADO, etc.

I've used SQL to manipulate the data. If you need help on that then you can look here:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp